# Array of dates, check if date exists

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object Member,

```
Member
 PropertyA
 PropertyZ
 Membership[] Memberships
```

and Membership object is

```
Membership
 PropertyA
 PropertyZ
 string Status
 DateTime? StartDate 
 DateTime? EndDate
```

If I now have,

```
var members = GetAllMembers(DateTime.Now);
```

I want to find out if member has any active membership today,

```
   // iterating through each member here
   if(member.Memberships.Any())
   {
       // check if user has any membership duration that falls into 
       // today's date and membership status is also "active"
   }
```

**Problem is,**

I am not sure how to check if any membership duration that falls into today's date and membership status is also "active"

Comment: So what is the problem/question?

Comment: @Markus update my question

Answer (score 2):

to check that the targetdt(DateTime.Now) is between StartDate & EndDate:

```
if (member.Memberships.Any(x=>targetDt.Ticks > x.StartDate.Ticks && targetDt.Ticks < x.EndDate.Ticks && x.Status=="Active"))
{
    // Has membership on targetDt.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that null value for start or end date means 'open' interval

```
var today = DateTime.Now;
var activeMembers = allMembers.Where(m => 
    m.Memberships.Any(ms => 
        ms.Status == "Active" &&
        (ms.StartDate == null || ms.StartDate <= today) && (ms.EndDate == null || today <= ms.EndDate)));
```

Comment: Looks good, but shouldn't we only compare the date instead of the full datetime? Just to avoid weird bugs ...

Comment: @Markus who knows. Sometimes membership end time can be till 6 PM. If we'll check just date we can have some issues. It depends on particular implementation :) It can also be till 00:00:00 of tomorrow, so checking against time after midnight will not pass. Or it can be 23:59:59 (usually we use this approach). So I prefer exact checking against current time with hours and seconds.

Comment: yes indeed - i just thought it might be dates, since OP has called his variables StarteDate and EndDate... and your variable is called `today`... should be `now` i guess

Answer (score 2):

So I would structure your main classes slightly more different from what you have now. This it to get of having to compare on strings for the status, but since I don't know exactly how the `active` property is set but I would assume that for a membership to be active the start and (optional) end date have to be smaller than and greater than today's date.

```
class Member
{
    private readonly IList<Membership> memberships;

    public Member()
    {
        memberships = new List<Membership>();
    }

    public ReadOnlyCollection<Membership> Memberships 
    { 
        get
        {
            return new ReadOnlyCollection<Membership>(memberships);
        }
    }
}

class Membership
{
    private readonly DateTime endDate;

    private readonly DateTime startDate;

    public Membership(DateTime startDate)
    {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    DateTime StartDate 
    {
        get
        {
            return this.startDate;
        }
    }

    DateTime? EndDate 
    { 
        get
        {
            return endDate;
        }
    }

    public Status Status
    {
        get
        {
            return CalculateMemebershipStatus();
        }
    }

    private Status CalculateMemebershipStatus()
    {
        var todaysDate = DateTime.Today;

        if (StartDate > todaysDate)
        {
            return Status.Deactivated;
        }

        if (!EndDate.HasValue)
        {
            return Status.Active;
        }

        if (todaysDate < EndDate.Value)
        {
            return Status.Active;
        }

        return Status.Deactivated;
    }
}

enum Status
{
    Active,
    Deactivated
}
```

And when you need to find out all the members that have an `active` membership today you can do:

```
var memberCollection = new List<Member>();
...
var activeMembers = memberCollection.Where(x => x.Memberships.Any(y=> y.Status == Status.Active));
```

So this will go through your member collection and select the ones that have an active status today. Although as previously said this depends on how you build the `active` property but this is more contained in that testing for the activeness of the `membership` based on the date is done within the membership object. So the consumer of this data doesn't need to know how to say that a `membership` is `active` they simply only need to know that some will be active and others will be deactivated.